# Flutter - Navigator.push() giving error "Context does not include a Navigator" on extends State<Main>

Tags: flutter

I've been creating a flutter app for a society and i'm using flutter.
I have created two "window" (I don't really know the technical terms on flutter),
The first one will display correctly with a button to switch on the second.
If you click on the button the other window will display correctly.
But, i want to use DeepLinks (for the notifications), and if i click on the link, the redirect in the _AccueilPageState to the Pub class (I'm using

```
Navigator.push(context,MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) =>  Pub()));
```

I got the error

> Navigator operation requested with a context that does not include a
> Navigator

Someone can explain me what is wrong ? And maybe how to fix this issue !
Thanks,
Here you can see the hierachi of my code (I can't show all of it because of confidentiality):

```
void main() async{...}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return this;
  }
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _AccueilPageState();
}
//Loading properties for MyApp(with the navigator.push in it)
class _AccueilPageState extends State<MyApp>{...}

//class loading FenetrePrincipale
class WebView extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(home : FenetrePrincipale(),
    );
  }
}
//Pub that return a MaterialApp(home:Builder:(context)=>Scaffold())
class Pub extends StatelessWidget{...}

//FenetrePrincipale that return a Scaffold
class FenetrePrincipale extends StatelessWidget{...}

//When on FenetrePrincipale we can push a button to open Pub but if you go trough a deeplink : _AccueilPageState
//Does not redirect on Pub and put the error :
//"Navigator operation requested with a context that does not include a Navigator"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Create a global key for the navigator so you can access it from anywhere in the application:

```
final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> myNavigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
```

2. Assign it to your app when creating `MaterialApp`:

```
return MaterialApp(navigatorKey: myNavigatorKey,...);
```

3. Use it when pushing routes:

```
myNavigatorKey.currentState?.pushNamed(...);
```

Comment: It is working perfectly, thanks ! But if i resume, i juste create a globalKey that is containing my context, so if there is a context, the app will push the globalKey context ?

Comment: You need to create the `GlobalKey` only once, it will provide access to the navigator without context.

Comment: But is it possible to pass some arguments trough the NavigatorKey ?

Comment: You mean when pushing a route? You can add arguments to routes when pushing them, [check out this](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/navigate-with-arguments).

Comment: I wish i could upvoted this four times